# Selenium Implicit Timeout stopped working

Tags: java, api, selenium

I'm creating an API based on Selenium API for our system that is controlled through the web-browser (similar to the way you control routers and switches).

One of the things that happens in this API is checking whether certain elements exist on the page (depending on the setting, they may or may not exit, for example, text box or some status).

I have this line:

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

I had it working just fine until when at one point in time, I ran it, and the driver.findElement(By....); has never timed out (the element was missing from the web-page)... The longest I have waited was somewhere about half-an hour.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 x64 as my host, Windows 7 as my guest, and on it I have my Selenium API and the code written in Java that controls out product. When I port the same code to another Windows VM or even to a different work station, it works fine. Not on my particular VM though.

Tried "reinstalling" eclipse, reimported Selenium JARs, pulled the latest working code from the server... Nothing works...

What are your thoughts, fellas?

Will appreciate any response. Thanks.

Comment: How are you sure selenium stopped at that step and not on the next?

Comment: I have stepped through the test with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all try using fluentWait to wait for all the AJAX on the page:

```
 public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);
        WebElement foo = wait.until(
                new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                    }
                }
        );
        return  foo;              }     ;
fluentWait(By.xpath(....blablabla..)).click();
//fluentWait(By.xpath(....blablabla..)).getText();
```

Secondly, try using `Thead.sleep(1000);` as alternative to

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Thank you for your algorithm, this definitely deserves a check-mark, but this has not solved the problem (as I said, code works on the other physical machine and VMs), it's this particular VM that does not work. So, it is not Selenium, not Eclipse... Windows of Ubuntu host... Those are my thoughts. I will give you a thumbs-up, but a bit later, otherwise people will stop posting answers.